# What's so special about bread?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-factorization

Why is bread highlighted? It's not lit any differently to the other barrels.

[image]

Comment: If you think bread is special wait till you see thing we're calling *sliced* bread

Comment: It kinda looks like the *other* barrels are suffering the usual lighting bugs and that the bread barrel is the only one properly lit.

Comment: Your cursor is over it.  What happens if you hover over something else?

Comment: @MBraedley Nope, makes no difference.

Comment: ...what if you swap the bread barrel with another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is most likely just a lighting glitch, which for some reason focuses on your bread barrel. For me, all my barrels light up when I point at one with my gravity gun. There's nothing special about it, just a few glitches in the coding. Replace the bread with something else and try a different barrel for it, it should be fixed then.

EDIT: Here, look at some nice pictures of my barrels. The first one shows the lighting glitch resolved, the second one with the light glitches.

[image: Lighting glitches fixed]
[image: Light glitches return]

---

HEY! Lookie here! The same problem occurs with signs!

[image]
[image]

Comment: Agree. I see this kind of highlighting with Factorization barrels regularly. Sometimes XyCraft's Aluminium ore is brighter than at other times.

Comment: I've got it with a long row of iron chests too.

Comment: I've been working on a custom block mod lately. Good god, writing bug-free custom block renderers is ***hard***. Lighting bugs like this are almost inevitable.